# Impact of dropping SHA1 code signing (SHA256 only)

Tags: code-signing, sha1, sha256, authenticode

I would like to know what is the impact of dropping SHA1 code signing in favour of SHA256-only code signing as of October 2018. I am currently dual code signing my executables to ensure they will get validated on all versions of Windows starting from Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2. There are many articles online showing code signing requirement matrices, but it's not so clear how many environments in practice won't validate SHA256-only signatures. From what I understood, SHA256 code signing support came in an update in Windows 7, but I don't know if this update is widely installed.

The reason I am asking is because I know it is just a matter of time before SHA256 is supported on all versions of Windows that are not in their end of life, and I am considering using AzureSignTool (https://github.com/vcsjones/AzureSignTool) which doesn't support SHA1 code signing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's not so clear how many environments in practice won't validate SHA256-only signatures.

Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2 without [KB3033929](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3033929/microsoft-security-advisory-availability-of-sha-2-code-signing-support) will be affected.
Windows 8 or later is OK.

> From what I understood, SHA256 code signing support came in an update in Windows 7, but I don't know if this update is widely installed.

I don't know too.
KB3033929 is included automatic Windows Update, but sometimes I get a question about this from Windows7 user (who don't install KB3033929).